# Can I change gnu make parallelism factor on the fly?

Tags: makefile, distcc

I want to run my make with -j8 if I'm not using distcc, but -j40 if distcc is enabled.

If I don't figure out whether or not I can use distcc until deep in the execution of the makefile, is there a way to change the -j factor at that late date?  Or do I have to make the decision in a wrapper script before I invoke make?  (I really don't want to run make recursively, with a different -j factor in the sub-make).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to change the number of jobs on the fly.  The jobserver is configured right at the beginning of make, and it's not possible to reconfigure it with a different size without restarting make.